GNU Radio - loop output tags back to flowgraph input
I'm new to GNU Radio. I have a fairly simple flow graph that generates a signal, then a Python block analyses the signal and adds a tag to the peak values.
At the moment, the output passes a message back to a phase adjustment block at the beginning of the flow graph to adjust the signal generation based on when the peaks had occurred. This works but is way too slow.
I have tried another method of taking the tagged output of the flow graph and feeding it into the beginning of the flow graph where the signals are generated. The intention is for the signal generation block to read the tags that were added to the output of the flow graph and adjust the signal that is being generated accordingly - I thought that this might be faster than the asynchronous message passing system.
The problem is that when I loop the output of the flow graph back to the beginning, I get the error: "RuntimeError: flow graph has loops!".
I am guessing the issue is that in this configuration, there is no output data until some of the signal has been processed, and if the input block is relying on input from the output of the flow graph, there is nothing to process at the beginning.
I would be grateful for any helpful suggestions.

Hi! This is a tough problem, as GNU Radio does not support stream loops (hence the error). What is it exactly that you want to build? There might be elegant ways to achieve the same, but I don't really know what "the same" would be…

Hi, thanks for your comment. I found out that GNU Radio doesn't do loops, which is frustrating. This is particularly a problem when I am trying to simulate my system. I have switched to transmitting the signal with an SDR and connecting the Tx to the Rx, then trying to process that Rx signal and feed it back into the beginning of the flow graph. This works in principal, but now I am getting a lot of data flow problems, i.e. packets dropping out. I should probably start a new thread for this problem as it is different to the original question.

yes! Please describe what you want to simulate, exactly! As said, I/ we can probably help you do that, without need for a loopback connection, but it would require understanding of what you're actually trying to simulate. You can edit your question here and add all the details!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
